# jQuery XML parsing: 2 equally named XML tags. How to only take the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have this XML that I am parsing with jQuery like this:

```
$(this).find("city").text()
```

Everything works fine, but in some cases the XML file contains the  tag twice and therefore duplicating the city in the parsed output like 'New YorkNew York' or 'ParisParis'.

How do I only take the first XML  tag, when there is a second, and completely ignore the second?

Answer (score 2):

You can just call [the `.first()` method](http://api.jquery.com/first) to eliminate the extra matches:

```
$(this).find("city").first().text()
```

Or you can use [the `:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to limit your results in the search itself:

```
$(this).find("city:first").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find("city:first").text()
```

That should do it.